# Trouble matching Name Servers in PHP with regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

Here is my regular expression: `/Name [Ss]ervers?:\s([\S]+\s){0,2}/`

As the script will mainly be parsing .co.uk and .com domains, I have sample results from WhoIs as follows;

.com: `Name Server: NS1.EXAMPLE.COM NS2.EXAMPLE.COM`

.co.uk `Name servers: dns1.registrar-servers.com dns2.registrar-servers.com`

Hence the strange match for 'Name Servers' as one result is non plural and capitalised and the other is not.

I am writing the script in PHP and the match part is as follows:

`preg_match('/Name [Ss]ervers?:\s([\S]+\s){0,3}/', $whoisRes, $match)`

The code is working for the .com results but not for the .co.uk results, and for the life of me I do not know why! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the full WhoIs response for a .co.uk domain:

```
WhoIs Result: 
Domain name: example-domain.co.uk 
Data validation: Nominet was not able to match the registrant's name and/or address against a 3rd party source on 23-Mar-2017 
Registrar: eNom LLC [Tag = ENOM] 
URL: http://www.enom.com 
Relevant dates: 
Registered on: 23-Mar-2017 
Expiry date: 23-Mar-2019 
Last updated: 26-Mar-2018 
Registration status: Registered until expiry date. 
Name servers: dns1.registrar-servers.com dns2.registrar-servers.com 

WHOIS lookup made at 12:26:52 31-May-2018 -- This WHOIS information is provided for free by Nominet UK the central registry for .uk domain names. This information and the .uk WHOIS are: Copyright Nominet UK 1996 - 2018. You may not access the .uk WHOIS or use any data from it except as permitted by the terms of use available in full at https://www.nominet.uk/whoisterms, which includes restrictions on: (A) use of the data for advertising, or its repackaging, recompilation, redistribution or reuse (B) obscuring, removing or hiding any or all of this notice and (C) exceeding query rate or volume limits. The data is provided on an 'as-is' basis and may lag behind the register. Access may be withdrawn or restricted at any time.
```

There is more code than this obviously, and forgive the messiness (I am just testing the data at the moment before I make the actual script):

```
$re = '/(?:\G(?!\A)|Name Servers?:)\h*\K\S+/i';
if (preg_match_all($re, $whoisRes, $matches)) {
    $name_servers = $matches;
} 
if (preg_match('/Creation Date: ([0-9]+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+)/i', 
$whoisRes, $match)) {
    $domain_date = trim($match[1]);
    $creation_date = strtotime(trim($match[1]));
    $domainage = dateDiff("now", $creation_date) . "\n";
} elseif (preg_match('/Registered on: ([0-9]+\-[a-zA-Z]+\-[0-9]+)/i', 
$whoisRes, $match)) {
    $domain_date = trim($match[1]);
    $creation_date = strtotime(trim($match[1]));
    $domainage = dateDiff("now", $creation_date) . "\n";
} else {
    $domainage = 'No Registration Date Found';
}
echo "URL: $url [$online]<br><br>";
echo "Load Time: $response_text [$overall_text]<br><br>";
echo "Name Servers:"; var_dump($name_servers); echo"<br><br>";
echo "Title: $title<br><br>";
echo "Description: $description<br><br>";
echo "Keywords: $keywords<br><br>";
echo "WhoIs Result: $whoisRes<br><br>";
echo "Domain Age: $domainage [$domain_date]<br><br>";
```

Comment: Are you simply trying to fetch all the name severs after `Name Server:`-part? _Note:_ If you add the flag `i` at the end, like `/your-regex/i`, the match will be case insensitive.

Comment: Yes I am, I've just tried both the answers below, and still only working for the .com results as with my original regular expression. Will edit the question to include the full WhoIs response for .co.uk domains.

Comment: What do you want to extract? Maybe [`'~(?:\G(?!\A)|Domain name:|Name Servers?:)\h*\K\S+~i'`](https://regex101.com/r/dSzpDB/3)?

Comment: I don't see why the domain name would matter. The regex doesn't care about that at all. There must be something else. Can you show us your complete code? Testing with vks's answer https://regex101.com/r/exRWmS/1 works...

Comment: Hopefully that helps! Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: With vks's answer in my code, it's like I get 2 matches, but they are empty strings? `array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
'~(?:\G(?!\A)|Name Servers?:)\h*\K\S+~i'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dSzpDB/1)

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|Name Servers?:)` - `Name Server:` or `Name Servers:` or end of the previou successful match
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal spaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/2wDLBR):

```
$re = '/(?:\G(?!\A)|Name Servers?:)\h*\K\S+/i';
$str = 'Name Server: NS1.EXAMPLE.COM NS2.EXAMPLE.COM
Name servers: dns1.registrar-servers.com dns2.registrar-servers.com';
if (preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => NS1.EXAMPLE.COM
    [1] => NS2.EXAMPLE.COM
    [2] => dns1.registrar-servers.com
    [3] => dns2.registrar-servers.com
)
```

Comment: Still only working for the .com results :( , I have edited the question to include the full .co.uk response

Comment: If you plan to get the strings after `Domain name:`, add it to the regex: [`'~(?:\G(?!\A)|Domain name:|Name Servers?:)\h*\K\S+~i'`](https://regex101.com/r/dSzpDB/3)

Comment: No, I already have the domain name, It's just the name servers I require, never been so stumped

Comment: @LiamGallagher What output do you expect to get? We can't help if you do not provide the expected results.

Comment: The name servers, exactly how you have them in your result 'NS1.EXAMPLE.COM' etc, It is working on the .com response but not on the .co.uk response

Answer (score 1):

```
Name [Ss]ervers?:\s\K|\G(?!^)(\S+)(?:\s|$)
```

You can use something of this sort.See demo.Grab the groups.

https://regex101.com/r/V9VjHD/2

Comment: Still only working for the .com results :( , I have edited the question to include the full .co.uk response

Comment: @LiamGallagher which result should be matched and it isnt getting matched